# Python VK API Ошибка прав входа

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Удаление всех видеозаписей из аккаунта вк,доступ максимальный,маска = `140492254`.
Код:

```
import vk_api
vk_session = vk_api.VkApi("login","password")
vk_session.auth()
vk = vk_session.get_api()
list_videos=[]
videos_vk=vk.video.get(owner_id="id",count=200)
count_videos=videos_vk["count"]
if count_videos>200:
    count_videos=200
for y in range(count_videos):
    list_videos.append(videos_vk["items"][y]["id"])
for video in list_videos:
    vk.video.delete(video_id=video)
```

Ошибка :

```
vk_api.exceptions.ApiError: [7]Permission to perform this action is denied
```

Comment: Точно выдал все права?

Comment: @Spooti посмотрите маску